# I am creating a checkbox list with react-native-elements. How do I check only one box at a time?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, checkbox, react-native-elements

I am making a list of check boxes but when I press on one checkbox, it checks all of the checkboxes. I want to select one at a time.

I tried the sample code from react-native-elements 1.1.0 documentation as well as examples from other people but I cannot find the solution.

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      checked1: false,
      checked2: false,
    };
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <CheckBox
            checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
            uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
            title='checkbox 1'
            checkedColor='red'
            checked1={this.state.checked1}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ checked1: !this.state.checked1 })}
          />
          <CheckBox
            checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
            uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
            title='checkbox 2'
            checkedColor='red'
            checked2={this.state.checked2}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ checked2: !this.state.checked2 })}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to select one checkbox at a time (select the checkbox that I pressed on instead of selecting all at once).

Comment: instead of having the same state for both checkboxes, you'll need separate states for this. can you try adding states `checked1` and `checked2`, arranging them accordingly to their respective checkboxes?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I actually tried that but when I did that, when I click, it doesn't check any :( I'll update the code to show you what I did @kenmistry

Comment: oh. i shared my answer below and it's the exactly the same :P. can you take a look at the test link? i've got it working on my end. you can check the box individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i've created a simple test [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/simple-multi-check-test) for you.

basically, if you assigned a separate state for each checkbox individually, it would work.

```
  constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
        checked1: false,
        checked2: false,
      };
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <CheckBox
            checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
            uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
            title='checkbox 1'
            checkedColor='red'
            checked={this.state.checked1}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ checked1: !this.state.checked1 })}
          />
          <CheckBox
            checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
            uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
            title='checkbox 2'
            checkedColor='red'
            checked={this.state.checked2}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ checked2: !this.state.checked2 })}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I got it to work! I put checked1 and checked2 instead of checked. Thank you for your help :D @kenmistry